# Adding docs to zipfiles in SP

Tags: 2010

I have several documents that I need to update several other zipfiles with.  Is there a way to copy a single document into SharePoint zipfiles without having to download each file to my computer and then reload the entire zipfile?  I tried viewing it as an explorer but with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's a CodePlex project that's been around for awhile that does exactly this. Just download and drop it in. Works great!

http://mzakicustomactions.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the source files and the zip files are both stored in SharePoint, then yes, you must copy them down manually in order to update the zip file with every change.  The only other alternatives I can think of are:

- Create an event receiver that would update the zip files
  anytime the source files changed
- Create a Timer job that would check for changes and then rebuild the
  zip files nightly
- Create a module that could be called via the ribbon that would
  dynamically build the zip file upon request